# Jquery : Keypress appends data with youtube results, how to refresh the result with new data?

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/eLhLS/1/

**Current:**

```
On keypress, it keeps on appending results from youtube
```

**Required:**

```
On keypress, update the results, with new data instead of appending it
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/eLhLS/37/?

Comment: Yes, but my preference is to keep html in HTML file rather than in js file, to make things simpler and neater

Comment: @daydreamer I have edited the fiddle and updated the link in my answer

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the wonderful answer, now I am getting sense of why jQuery is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/eLhLS/38/

```
     $(function(){
    $('#search-input').live('keyup',function() {
        // alert('hi');
        var clone = $('#result').find('.item').clone();

        $('#result').html('');
        $("#result").html(clone); 
        var search_input = $(this).val();
        var keyword = encodeURIComponent(search_input);
        var yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+keyword+'&format=5&max-results=10&v=2&alt=jsonc';

        $.ajax({
          url: yt_url,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            //called when complete
          },
          success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            if(response.data.items) {
                $.each(response.data.items, function(i, data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    search_data = {
                        'id': data.id,
                        'title': data.title,
                        'views': data.viewCount,
                        'thumbnail': data.thumbnail['sqDefault'],
                    }
                    var item = $('#result .item').clone().removeClass('item');
                    video_result_template(item, search_data).appendTo('#result').fadeIn(); // slow/fast?
                });
            } else {

            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //called when there is an error
          }
        });

    });
});

function video_result_template(item, data) {
    item.find('.thumbnail').text(data.thumbnail);
    item.find('.title').text(data.title);
    item.find('.views').text(data.views);
    return item;
}
​
```

​

Comment: This still appends the result plus, I have to press "Enter" to get the result which is not desirable

Comment: hahah.. sorry, i kept on forgetting to change all the parts of the answer at once. I gave the wrong jsfiddle link, Now js fiddle link updated

Comment: That works well, but is this the best way to do this? I mean I need to keep HTML at two places? in a file and in jQuery syntax?

Comment: actually u can do it in a cleaner way. You need not remove your 'item's , instead you need to set the results using .text() and then on a new load empty the results using .text('')

Comment: and any example of how can I do that? I am very new to jQuery

Comment: ok edited. I think I can refactor more, But i will leave it for you. You should probably get an idea now. Also , is this the best way fo doing? No, There can be multiple ways, You can also do this without even using an extra function - video_result_template. But you have to spend more time!

Comment: awesome, this is prefect, and easily understood, thanks much Eswar :)

Comment: check out @slash197 fiddle too